# pandas - count size and frequency of different groupby levels

Tags: python, pandas

After some groupby operations I have this resulting dataframe:

```
GridCode  User_ID    DLang
3         224591119  es       
                     ja        
                     zh        
4         224591119  es        
6         146381773  en        
9         17925282   ca        
          63102456   en        
          106225728  ca        
          229125779  ca
```

I would like to count, for each `GridCode`, the number of `User_ID`s within each `DLang`, building new columns such as 'User_ID_(DLang)' The resulting dataframe would appear as:

```
GridCode User_ID_es User_ID_ja User_ID_zh ...
3 1 1 1 ...
4 1 0 0 ...
6 0 0 0 ...
```

So far I get some results with the unstuck method, but know I can't figured out how to count the User_IDs and their frequency.

Comment: I gave it a try but not sure what  you want.  It might be good to show desired results for ```GridCode=9``` since that one has duplicate values for ```Dlang```, unlike other rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, maybe something like this?

```
df.groupby(['GridCode','DLang']).count().unstack().fillna(0)

         User_ID            
DLang         ca en es ja zh
GridCode                    
3              0  0  1  1  1
4              0  0  1  0  0
6              0  1  0  0  0
9              3  1  0  0  0
```